# How to generate c# class file for internal class in dll

Tags: c#, winapi, dllimport, twain

All, I was trying to call the API which is defined in the DLL in the c# project. the code looks like below .

```
[DllImport("twain_32.dll", EntryPoint="#1")]
<Function declaration>
```

I know there are lots of public types which defined in this twain_32.dll,

and I knew there is function defined in the dll like below .

```
TW_UINT16 FAR PASCAL DSM_Entry( pTW_IDENTITY pOrigin,
                                  pTW_IDENTITY pDest,
                                  TW_UINT32    DG,
                                  TW_UINT16    DAT,
                                  TW_UINT16    MSG,
                                  TW_MEMREF    pData);
```

I don't know what class should I defined to reference in the c# to represent `pTW_IDENTITY`? Is there any tools to export all these type definition to c# class code . like header file `.h` in the c++ ?  thanks.

Comment: Find the documentation and the header file for the library, and translate it. Where did you find that function prototype?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found it in the header file (c++) of twain. But I was confused how to translate the referenced type to c# code. I had thought there would exist some tools make it work easier . thanks.

Comment: No tools. Translate it yourself, or see if you can't find an existing one. For example TwainDotNet. No point re-inventing the wheel. Your one might come out square!!  ;-)

Comment: :D That is exactly what I worried about ! and I think NO point reinventing a car! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool which would do this automatically, but there is a site called [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) which offers lots of P/Invoke signatures and examples. For your question, here is the link: [TwIdentity (twain_32)](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/twain_32.TwIdentity).

Also, there are open source libraries available which wrap the native functionality into managed classes, like: [Saraff.Twain.NET](http://sarafftwain.codeplex.com/) or [twain-in-dotnet](https://bitbucket.org/soukoku/twain-in-dotnet), so looking at their source code you will probably find all the definitions you need.

Comment: @Eoin: yeah, LOL, that was pretty simultaneous!

Comment: Thanks you two. It is what I need. Thanks the guys who did the great work for us, otherwise we have to do this so many times .

Answer (score 2):

PInvoke.net is a good resource for this.

They have some examples of the TWAIN_32 lib calls + a struct for `pTW_IDENTITY`

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/twain_32.TwIdentity